# getArguments() returns null when retrieving data from activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, fragment, bundle

I have two different activities :
1.Login.java
2.Dashboard.java

In dashboard activity i have added navigation drawer by making navigation drawer fragment appearing in dashboard activity.

Now i want to pass data to that navigation drawer fragment through login.java

Here is my code :

Login.java- All things are imported

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, OnItemSelectedListener{

private EditText loginid;
private EditText password;
private Spinner type;
private Button loginbtn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    loginid=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_loginid);
    password=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_password);
    loginbtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    type=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_type);

    loginbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    type.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    List<String> types = new ArrayList<String>();
      types.add("Student");
      types.add("Faculty");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, types);  
    type.setAdapter(adapter);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String id= loginid.getText().toString().trim();
    String pass= password.getText().toString().trim();
    String type_passed = type.getSelectedItem().toString().toLowerCase();
    LoginRequest(type_passed,id,pass);

}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public void LoginRequest(final String type_selected,String id,String pass)
{
    VolleySingleton volleySingleton = VolleySingleton.getInstance();
    RequestQueue requestQueue= volleySingleton.getRequestQueue();

    JsonObjectRequest jsonobject= new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            "http://10.0.2.2:80/noticeboardapi/loginrequest.php/?type="+type_selected+"&enrollid="+id+"&password="+pass+"",
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("type", type_selected);
                    NavigationDrawerFragment navfrag = new NavigationDrawerFragment();
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(type_selected.equals("student"))
                    {
                        try {
                            String enrollid = response.getString("enrollid");
                            String name = response.getString("name");
                            String section = response.getString("section");
                            String rollno = response.getString("rollno");
                            int status = Integer.parseInt(response.getString("status"));

                            switch(status)
                            {
                            case 0:
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    break;
                                }

                            case 1:
                                {

                                    navfrag.setArguments(bundle);
                                    Intent sloggedin= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Dashboard.class);
                                    startActivity(sloggedin);
                                    finish();
                                    break;
                                }

                            case 2:
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    break;
                                }

                            default:
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Request Not Accepted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    break;
                                }
                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }else if(type_selected.equals("faculty"))
                    {
                        try {
                            String enrollid = response.getString("enrollid");
                            String name = response.getString("name");
                            String cc = response.getString("cc");
                            String hod = response.getString("hod");
                            int status = Integer.parseInt(response.getString("status"));

                            switch(status)
                            {
                            case 0:
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect password Faculty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    break;
                                }

                            case 1:
                                {

                                    navfrag.setArguments(bundle);
                                    Intent floggedin= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Dashboard.class);
                                    startActivity(floggedin);
                                    finish();
                                    break;
                                }

                            case 2:
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Faculty does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    break;
                                }

                            default:
                                {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Request Not Accepted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    break;
                                }
                            }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }               

                }
            } , new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Response \n" + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
    requestQueue.add(jsonobject);
}

}
```

My Navigation Drawer Fragment.java:

```
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment implements NavigationListAdapter.ClickedListener{
public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME="testpref";
public static final String KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER="user_learned_drawer";

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private NavigationListAdapter adapter;
    private View containerView;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;  
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
  ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
   //Inflate the layout for this fragment

   String type = getArguments().getString("type");

   View layout = inflater.inflate(
              R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
   recyclerView= (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
   adapter= new NavigationListAdapter(getActivity(), getNavData("student"));
   adapter.setClickListener(this);
   recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
   recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
   return layout;
   }

   @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    HomeFragment home = new HomeFragment();
    transaction.replace(R.id.layout_dashboard, home, "Home");
    transaction.addToBackStack("home");
    transaction.commit();
   }



public static List<NavigationListContent> getNavData(String type){
List<NavigationListContent> data = new ArrayList<NavigationListContent>();
if(type.equals("student")){
    int[] icons= {R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher};
    String[] titles= {"Home","Profile","Contact Us"};

    for(int i =0;i<titles.length && i<icons.length;i++)
    {
        NavigationListContent current = new NavigationListContent();
        current.title=titles[i];
        current.iconId=icons[i];
        data.add(current);
    }

    }else if(type.equals("faculty"))
{
    int[] icons= {R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher};
    String[] titles= {"Home","Profile","Add Notice","Contact Us"};

    for(int i =0;i<titles.length && i<icons.length;i++)
    {
        NavigationListContent current = new NavigationListContent();
        current.title=titles[i];
        current.iconId=icons[i];
        data.add(current);
    }
   }

return data;

} 

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

mUserLearnedDrawer = Boolean.valueOf(readFromPreferences(getActivity(),KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER , "false")); 
if(savedInstanceState!=null)
{
    mFromSavedInstanceState=true;
}

}

   public void setUp(int fragmentID,DrawerLayout drawerLayout,Toolbar toolbar) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
containerView= getActivity().findViewById(fragmentID);
mDrawerLayout=drawerLayout;
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close){

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        if(!mUserLearnedDrawer)
        {
            mUserLearnedDrawer=true;
            saveToPreferences(getActivity(), KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, mUserLearnedDrawer+"");
        }

        getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

};
if(mUserLearnedDrawer &&mFromSavedInstanceState)
{
    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(containerView);

}
mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
});


 }

public static void saveToPreferences(Context context,String preferenceName,String preferenceValue){

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString(preferenceName, preferenceValue);
editor.apply();

}

 public static String readFromPreferences(Context context,String preferenceName,String preferenceValue){

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
return sharedPreferences.getString(preferenceName, preferenceValue);

   }

 @Override
 public void itemClicked(View view, int position) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
//startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), SubActivity.class));
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
switch(position)
{
case 0: 
    {   
        HomeFragment home = new HomeFragment();
        transaction.replace(R.id.layout_dashboard, home, "Home");
        transaction.addToBackStack("home");
        break;
    }

case 1:
    {
        ProfileFragment profile = new ProfileFragment();
        transaction.replace(R.id.layout_dashboard, profile, "Profile");
        transaction.addToBackStack("profile");
        break;
    }

case 2:
    {
        AddNoticeFragment addnotice = new AddNoticeFragment();
        transaction.replace(R.id.layout_dashboard, addnotice, "AddNotice");
        transaction.addToBackStack("addnotice");
        break;
    }

case 3:
    {
        ContactUsFragment contactus = new ContactUsFragment();
        transaction.replace(R.id.layout_dashboard, contactus, "ContactUs");
        transaction.addToBackStack("contactus");
        break;
    }

default:
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No such Option", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        transaction.addToBackStack("home");
        break;
    }
}
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
transaction.commit();
 }


    }
```

My Dashboard.java

```
public class Dashboard extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private DrawerLayout drawer_layout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

    toolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    drawer_layout=(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationDrawerFragment drawerfragment= (NavigationDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    drawerfragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer,drawer_layout,toolbar);

    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

    if (drawer_layout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.START)) { // replace this with
                                                    // actual function
                                                    // which returns if
                                                    // the drawer is
                                                    // open
        drawer_layout.closeDrawer(Gravity.START); // replace this with
                                                // actual function which
                                                // closes drawer
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.dashboard, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

Error received:

```
04-29 19:11:06.009: E/AndroidRuntime(3641): Caused by:     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method     'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null     object reference
```

I have tried many stackoverflow solution but no one works for me.
Please tell me what to do as i am stucked here for too much of time and thanks in advance!

Comment: you set arguments just in one case. So may be this the cause of your problem

Comment: checked that too..problem still persists..

Comment: try to set arguments after fragment creation. Will you get the same error?

Comment: thanks for your reply..Fragment is created when dashboard activity is created but i want to pass data to that fragment created when dashboard activity is invoked..

Comment: Why don't you try passing that data to your new activity, and then from the activity it'll be very easy to pass data to NavigationDrawerFragment(simple method call)?

Comment: Right now you're creating a fragment in login activity which is never added to the view in dashboard.

Comment: thanks...i have tried that too ..i sent that data to dashboard activity through intent and then passed to fragment though bundle..still error persists..

Comment: there are many buggs in your code... 1st big bug is you are adding fragment in inside fragment.....!!!